# How to run HPL on multiple Nvidia GPUs locally?

Tags: nvidia, high-performance

I am trying to run HPL benchmark on my cluster. I want to run it locally and the file I use is `hpl-2.0-FERMIV15`. However, I don't know how to run this with multiple GPUs locally. I don't know how to check whether my HPL is being run on GPU and whether or not it is being run on multiple GPUs.

I have also had a look at the Nvidia official site and it seems that they only provide the docker image, and they don't have any instructions on how to run HPL locally on multiple Nvidia GPUS.

I am curious to know if anyone else has done similar things before, since it's also very hard to find related resources on the Internet.